# How should I be handling authentication with Identity 2.0 and WebAPI 2.1 and Owin 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using

- New browser only clients on the same domain
- Identity 2.0
- WebAPI 2.1
- Owin 2.1
- AngularJS front-end for registration, login and data display

In a WebAPI application with an AngularJS front-end.

I'm reading about token authentication but I am very confused now and I cannot find any good examples out there that use my combination. What I would like to know is should I be using cookies or tokens for the authentication. Should I be using a Userfactory or the CreatePerOwinContext?

Here's what I have in my Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
    }
```

Here's my WebAPI config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void CustomizeConfig(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ" });
    }
```

I saw some examples using this code but I am not sure how I can call this:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

Could I just replace the cookie authentication with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but in my dabbling I've found that tokens work great for api and from javascript to api, and traditional cookies lean mostly for a ui.  Either or both will work depending on what your trying to do.

You can follow something like this link that does cookie for the ui and token for the api  http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/03/asp-net-identity-2-0-cookie-token-authentication/

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationSession.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Token Authentication
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerOptions());
```

I think you can set the cookie authentication options authentication type to bearer if you want bearer for both, but you would have to play with it.  The token would be in the owincontext under ".AspNet.ExternalBearer".

I also think if you register the Identity 2.0 middleware i think it also registers the oauth middleware stuff so you don't need to register the oauthserver middleware yourself.  Thats the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions code you posted. You dont need it.

if the ui and api are in separate then its a bit harder if you want to do some sort of single sign on from the ui pass to the api.  I would recommend looking at opensource identity server or authorization server from [thinktecture](https://github.com/thinktecture).

If your set on owin middleware and Identity 2.0 you would need to make sure the token can be read by both application and api and you probably would need to implement ISecureDataFormat.  But remember, decryption doesn't mean you can 100% trust a token, it should be signed and verified. Depends on your needs.

Sorry, I guess thats a long ramble...  Good luck.